# Что такое "запрос" к google maps?

Tags: google-maps

появилась необходимость использования google maps в коммерческом ПО. На сайте google указана цена за количество запросов в месяц. А что такое "запрос"? Допустим я загрузил карту с утра и весь день ее не закрывал, пользовался и тд, это один запрос?

Comment: Думаю, что *запрос* неравно *запуск приложения*. Я бы сказала, что запрос это любая операция как поиск адреса, проложение маршрута и тд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На официальном сайте доступна информация по цене и описание, за что именно вы платите https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet